# Terminate makefile command when subcommand throws?

Tags: shell, makefile

I've got the following Makefile:

```
#runs the working directory unit tests
test:
    @NODE_ENV=test; \
        mocha --ignore-leaks $(shell find ./test -name \*test.js);

#deploys working directory
deploy:
    @make test; \
    make deploy-git; \
    make deploy-servers;

#deploys working to git deployment branch
deploy-git:
    @status=$$(git status --porcelain); \
    if test "x$${status}" = x; then \
        git branch -f deployment; \
        git push origin deployment; \
        echo "Done deploying to git deployment branch."; \
    else \
        git status; \
        echo "Error: cannot deploy. Working directory is dirty."; \
    fi

deploy-servers:
#   for each server
#       @DEPLOY_SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"; \
#       make deploy-server

#deploy-server:
#   connect to this server with ssh
#   check if app is already running
#   stop the app on the server if already running
#   set working directory to app folder
#   update deployment git branch
#   use git to move head to deployment branch
#   start app again
```

Note that `deploy-servers` and `deploy-server` are just dummies for now. This is what the `deploy` command should do:

1. run the tests (`make test`), exit on failure
2. push current head to deployment branch (`make deploy-git`), exit on failure
3. pull deployment branch on servers (`make deploy-servers`)

You can see this in the Makefile as:

```
deploy:
    @make test; \
    make deploy-git; \
    make deploy-servers;
```

The issue is that I am not sure how to prevent `make deploy-git` from executing when `make test` fails, and how to prevent `make deploy-servers` from executing when the tests fail or when `make deploy-git` fails.

Is there a clear way to do this, or should I resort to using shell files or write these tools in a normal programming language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exit status of a shell command *list* is the exit status of the last command in the list. Simply turn your command list into separate single *simple commands*. By default, `make` stops when a command returns nonzero. So you get what you want with

```
deploy:
    @make test
    make deploy-git
    make deploy-servers
```

Should you ever **want** to ignore the exit status of a simple command, you can prefix it with a dash:

```
 target:
     cmd1
     -cmd2 # It is okay if this fails
     cmd3
```

Your `make` manual has all the details.

Comment: +1, but note to the OP, you probably want to (at least) do `make test $(MAKEFLAGS)` to propagate any additional command line flags through to the subsidiary make.

Comment: @William - that depends, as my make (GNU Make 3.81) seems to automatically do this.  I just tested because your comment made me nervous.

Answer (score 6):

Others have given answers which are based on splitting the "recipe" into individual commands.

In situations where that is not viable, what you can do is `set -e` in the shell script to make it terminate if a command fails:

```
target:
        set -e ; \
          command1 ; \
          command2 ; command3 ; \
          ... commandN
```

This is the same `set -e` that you would put near the top of a shell script to get it to bail when some command terminates unsuccessfully.

Suppose that we are not interested in the termination statuses of `command2` and `command3`. Suppose it is okay if these indicate failure, or do not reliably use termination status. Then, instead of `set -e` we can code an explicit exit test:

```
target:
        command1 ; \
        command2 || exit 1 ; \
        command3 ; \
        true  # exit 0 will do here also.
```

Since `command3` can indicate failure, and we don't want it to fail our build, we add a successful dummy command.

Comment: Very nice of you to extend the given answers with such useful information. I wish I could accept a multitude of answers..

Answer (score 2):

`make` should already do this; it executes complex commands with `sh -e`, which (as long as it's not in a loop in a POSIX compatible shell) will abort execution if a command exits nonzero, and aborts the entire `Makefile` on failure of a command unless you specifically tell it not to.  If you're feeling paranoid, you can use `&&` in place of `;` in your commands.

Comment: I'm interested to know more about this (_"it executes complex commands with `sh -e` [and] will abort execution if a command exits nonzero"_).  Does anyone have a reference link with more information?

Comment: That's what I'd expect, but my version of GNU Make (4.4.1 on OSX) needs an explicit `|| exit 1` or `set -e`. That doesn't seem right but it very clearly doesn't fail when a `${MAKE} whatever` fails. My cases are all with `.PHONY` targets.

Comment: In my case, I had to add an explicit `.SHELLFLAGS = -ec` to my Makefile. There are many resources that say that should be the default; but it wasn't for me. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this very issue by proxying to a new make command at the potential breakpoint:

```
.PHONY cmd_name cmd_name_contd

cmd_name:
    if [ "`pwd`" = "/this/dir" ]; then make cmd_name_contd; fi

cmd_name_contd:
    @echo "The directory was good, continuing"
```

That way, if the directory was wrong, it just exits silently, you could also add an else condition with a message to display on failure.